# What is a good practice to copy vector data to a tuple with different element data type?

Tags: c++, vector, copy, tuples

I'm using GCC 4.8.3 with C++11.

I have a `std::vector<uint8_t>` and I need to copy its content to a `std::tuple`.
The tuple elements describe the data structure of the vector.
Exp.: `std::tuple<uint32_t,uint16_t>` would correspond with a vector of 6 bytes where the first four bytes belongs to `uint32_t` and the second two bytes to `uint16_t`.

This is requirement is not changeable, because it is part of a larger templated class but broken down to simplify my question.

**Edit:** Endianess is guaranteed to be correct. *Thank you WhozCraig*

What I have now is following two variants

```
template<typename T, int TupleIndex, unsigned int BufferPosition>
void extractBufferToTuple(T&& tuple, std::vector<uint8_t>&buffer) {
    std::get<TupleIndex>(tuple) = *(typename std::tuple_element<TupleIndex,T>::type*)&buffer[BufferPosition];
}
```

and

```
template<typename T, int TupleIndex, unsigned int BufferPosition>
void extractBufferToTuple(T&& tuple, std::vector<uint8_t>&buffer) {
    std::copy(&buffer[BufferPosition], &buffer[BufferPosition] + sizeof(typename std::tuple_element<TupleIndex,T>::type), (uint8_t*)&std::get<TupleIndex>(tuple));
}
```

Calling it would look something like this

```
std::tuple<uint32_t,uint32_t> myTuple;
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
buffer.resize(6);
uint32_t value0 = 123;
uint16_t value1 = 456;
std::copy((uint8_t*)&value0,(uint8_t*)&value0+sizeof(value0),&buffer[0]);
std::copy((uint8_t*)&value1,(uint8_t*)&value1+sizeof(value1),&buffer[sizeof(value0)]);


extractBufferToTuple<decltype(myTuple),0,0>(std::forward<decltype(testClass)::Tuple>(myTuple),buffer);        
extractBufferToTuple<decltype(myTuple),1,sizeof(std::tuple_element<0,decltype(myTuple)>::type)>(std::forward<decltype(myTuple)>(myTuple),buffer);
```

Is either one a valid and safe approach or is there some better practice whithout any possible pitfalls?

Comment: Ignoring the obvious breakdown when source vs target endian representation isn't consistent?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. This is also guaranteed.

Comment: Note on signature: An rvalue reference for an _out_ parameter seems questionable.  If someone passes in a temporary then the output is not usable.  This only complicates the implementation with almost no obvious benefit.  Also, read-only sources should be passed by reference to _const_.  (Passing a non-const lvalue reference says to callers, "I may modify this object.")

Comment: Those are very good hints. Was not thinking about that but makes completly sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename T>
size_t extractBuffer(const std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer, size_t start_index, T* to) {
  std::memcpy(to, &buffer[start_index], sizeof(*to));
  return start_index + sizeof(*to);
}

template <typename ... Ts>
size_t extractBuffer(const std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer, size_t start_index,
                     std::tuple<Ts...>* to) {
  auto extractHelper = [&](auto& ... elems) {
    auto _ = {(start_index = extractBuffer(buffer, start_index, &elems)) ...};
    return start_index;
  };
  return std::apply(extractHelper, *to);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MPMf5M)

Comment: I guess we could rewrite the std::apply so I could use it in C++11?

Comment: `std::apply` could be replaced with a slightly more verbose approach based on `std::index_sequence`. The latter is a C++14 feature, but it's trivial to roll one's own in C++11, much easier than `std::apply`. You should be able to find one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and implement it in C++11. But your approach looks very nice.

Comment: Was there any thought in using memcpy instead of copy in this specific case? Just wondering

Comment: `static_cast<void>(_);` might also be useful to silent warning for unused variable.

Comment: Technically, things like `*(int*)buf` exhibit undefined behavior, by way of violating strict aliasing rules. Though you are highly likely to get away with it (this kind of code is very common, so compilers tend to take care to allow this). `memcpy` avoids this undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah, you are asking about `memcpy` vs `std::copy`. Shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Had bit of a struggle to get it to work but this is what I came up with for C++11. It is not as sleek as Igor

```
template<size_t TupleIndex>
struct ExtractBufferToTuple {
    template<typename T, typename Iterator>
    static inline void extractBufferToTuple(T& tuple, Iterator bufferPosition) {
        auto nextBufferPosition = bufferPosition - sizeof (typename ::std::tuple_element<TupleIndex, T>::type);
        std::copy(nextBufferPosition, bufferPosition, (uint8_t*) & ::std::get<TupleIndex>(tuple));
        ExtractBufferToTuple < TupleIndex - 1 > ::extractBufferToTuple(tuple, nextBufferPosition);
    }
};

template<>
struct ExtractBufferToTuple<0> {
    template<typename T, typename Iterator>
    static inline void extractBufferToTuple(T& tuple, Iterator bufferPosition) {
        auto nextBufferPosition = bufferPosition - sizeof (typename ::std::tuple_element<0, T>::type);
        std::copy(nextBufferPosition, bufferPosition, (uint8_t*) & ::std::get<0>(tuple));
    }
};

template<typename T, typename ... TArgs>
void extractBufferToTuple(T& tuple,const std::vector<uint8_t>&buffer) {
    size_t tupleByteSize = byteSize < TArgs...>();
    if (buffer.size() == tupleByteSize) {
        ExtractBufferToTuple<::std::tuple_size<typename ::std::decay<T>::type>::value - 1 > ::extractBufferToTuple(tuple, buffer.end());
    }
}
```